# Sort two QVector

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt

I have got two `QVector<double>`s `x` and `y`. Actually that vectors represent data points A(x[0], y[0]), B(x[1],y[1]), and so on. Now I want to sort `x` and modify `y` so that data points still be like A(x[n], y[n]). For example if I have `x`{3,6,1,5} and `y`{9,2,1,5} I should receive: x{1,3,5,6} and `y`{1,9,5,2}. Is there any algorithm for that?

Comment: I don't know about any algorithms in Qt that would do the trick. Is it possible to create a struct which holds x and y together? Then you could implement its comparison operators to compare the xs so a vector of these structs can be passed to any sorting algorithm. Otherwise i'm afraid you have to implement the sort yourself.

Comment: I should note that performance is very important. My `QVector`s length is thousands, so creating new `QVector`, `QMap` or another container is not suitable. I would store data points in `QMap`, but I need x-values (and y-values) to be stored in adjacent memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily merge the vectors (for example using a [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/)), then do the sorting (with [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)) and then finally split the pairs into two vectors again.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in several ways, one is to use an intermediary map container and exploit the fact that `<key,value>` pairs are ordered by the key:

```
QVector<int> x = {2,1,0};
QVector<int> y = {3,2,1};

QMap<int, int> map;
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) // Assume vectors have the same size
     map.insert(x[i], y[i]);

QList<int> xl = map.keys();
QList<int> yl = map.values();

x = QVector<int>::fromList(xl); // {0,1,2}
y = QVector<int>::fromList(yl); // {1,2,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no Qt function which will do what you want. Sorting algorithms are not that complicated so you will have to write your own code to implement it and just have the y-vector tag along so that any operation on the x-vector is repeated on the y-vector.  I'm sure someone has already coded this but it might not be published anywhere where you can find it.  That said, you can certainly find example code that does the sorting and then add in your y-vector portion.